# Is every radon-nikodym derivative a random variable?

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, lebesgue-measure, density-function, geometric-measure-theory

Let $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X}, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu$ begin $\sigma$-finite.

> **Definition of Random Variable**: Let $(\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{Y})$ be a measurable space. A function $\xi:\mathsf{X}\to\mathsf{Y}$ is a random variable if $\xi^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{X}$ for every $A\in\mathcal{Y}$. We say that the random variable is a $\mathcal{X}$-measurable function.

> **Definition of Radon-Nikodym derivative**: Let $\lambda$ be $\sigma$-finite measure with $\mu \ll \lambda$. Then there exists a $\mathcal{X}$-measurable function $f:\mathsf{X}\to[0, +\infty)$ denoted
> $$
> f = \frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}
> $$
> satisfying
> $$
> \mu(A) = \int_A f d\lambda \qquad \forall A\in\mathcal{X}.
> $$

It seems that the Radon-Nikodym derivative is a $\mathcal{X}$-measurable function so by definition it should be a random variable between $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X})$ and $(\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}))$. Is this the case that every Radon-Nikodym derivative is a random variable?

Comment: Random variable is a measurable function on a probability space (i.e. $\mu(X) = 1$), not any measure space.

Comment: @ajr Ah! I have never noticed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short answer:* yes.

*Long answer:* the axiomatization of probability by Kolmogorov begins by giving suggestive names to familiar objects. For example, a mere "measurable function" is called "random variable". Of course, a "random variable" isn't random at all (by the way, to my knowledge, the word "random" has formal definitions only in some areas of math - see, for example, the definition of [Chaitin](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/321356.321363), as pointed out by @postmortes in the comments, that is more or less related to the "unpredictable" character of randomness - none of which are directly related to probability theory). So, any map between finite sets is a random variable, if one assumes that the finite sets are given the discrete $\sigma$-algebra. For example, the map sending each human being to its height in centimeters is a random variable. The identity map, from $\{4,7,56\}$ to itself, is also a random variable.

Now, probability theory, as a theory with fancy names, has proved to be very successful in modelling "true random events in real life", but this is another story; to understand why is a problem of dynamical systems, physics, maybe philosophy. But if it is just thought a branch of measure theory, it is just like any other mathematical theory.

Comment: Random certainly has a mathematical definition; generally Chaitin ( https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/321356.321363 ) gets the credit for it

Comment: I'll edit my answer, but Chaitin's definition does not cover "everything" that comes to mind when thinking of "randomness". Moreover, I have never seen a book of probability theory mentioning this definition.

Comment: There's no need to edit your answer; I only wanted to provide you with additional insight :) I'm sorry it's not helped you.

Comment: It's okay, there is no reason for me to "hide the truth" :)!